# How to tell if one goroutine succeeded or all goroutines are done?

Tags: go, depth-first-search, goroutine

I am trying to use DFS to check a graph for cycles by checking each node in the graph for a cycle.

I would like to run a goroutine for each node and terminate when the first cycle is detected or when there are no cycles.

Terminating when the first cycle is detected seems fine, but I am having trouble mixing that with when there aren't anymore nodes.

Below is an implementation that *seems* to work, but looks janky to me and I was looking for a better implementation. I essentially use buffered channels and increment a counter every time I don't get a cycle and terminate when the counter reaches the size of the underlying graph.

Using the counter to determine when we are done seems un-idiomatic to me. Or, rather, it'd be great to know if there is a more idiomatic way to do this in Go.

```golang
func (c *cycleDet) hasCycle() bool {
    adj := c.b // adjacency list representation of the unerlying graph
    hasCycles := make(chan bool, len(adj))

    for node := range adj {
        go func(no nodeID, co chan<- bool) {
            visited := make(map[nodeID]struct{})
            // c.nodeHasCycle will use a recursive implementation of DFS to
            // find out if the node no leads to a cycle.
            if c.nodeHasCycle(no, visited) {
                co <- true
                return
            }
            co <- false
        }(node, hasCycles)
    }

    var i int
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-hasCycles:
            if v {
                fmt.Println("got cycle")
                return true
            }
            if i == len(c.b) {
                return false
            }
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

I've also come across another SO post that recommended using an "observer" goroutine (although I can't find the SO post). I'm not sure what that would look like but imagine it would mix with `WaitGroup`s like this:

```golang
func (c *cycleDet) hasCycle() bool {
    hasCycle := make(chan bool)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    adj := c.b // adjacency list representation of the unerlying graph
    for node := range adj {
        go func(no nodeID, co chan<- bool) {
            // Use wg to synchronize termination of read-only goroutines.
            wg.Add(1)
            defer wg.Done()

            visited := make(map[nodeID]struct{})
            // c.nodeHasCycle will use a recursive implementation of DFS to
            // find out if the node no leads to a cycle.
            if c.nodeHasCycle(no, visited) {
                co <- true
                return
            }
        }(node, hasCycle)
    }

    // Observer goroutine to notify when wg is done waiting.
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    select {
    case <-hasCycle:
        fmt.Println("got a cycle")
        return true
    case <-done:
        fmt.Println("no cycle detected")
        return false
    }
}
```

However this approach worries me because I need to sleep for the observer to start waiting only after the first `WaitGroup` counter increments, which seems far more fragile than the first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that `WaitGroup` is probably what you want. However, you're not using it correctly. First, you need to call `wg.Add(1)` outside of the go routine that is calling `wg.Done()`. Second, calling `wg.Wait()` blocks until all the go routines in the wait group finish execution, so you don't want it to execute concurrently.

As for short-circuiting, there's not really a good way to do that. My advice would be to use a context. One thing you'll have to do in this case is to wire the context into your calls of `nodeHasCycle` if you want real short-circuiting behavior.

Fixing you code, we have:

```
func (c *cycleDet) hasCycle() bool {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    hasCycle := make(chan bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    adj := c.b // adjacency list representation of the unerlying graph
    for node := range adj {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(ctx context.Context, no nodeID, co chan<- bool, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
            // Use wg to synchronize termination of read-only goroutines.
            defer wg.Done()

            select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
            }

            visited := make(map[nodeID]struct{})
            // c.nodeHasCycle will use a recursive implementation of DFS to
            // find out if the node no leads to a cycle.
            if c.nodeHasCycle(ctx, no, visited) {
                co <- true
                cancel()
                return
            }
        }(ctx, node, hasCycle, cancel)
    }

    // Observer goroutine to notify when wg is done waiting.
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    wg.Wait()
    defer cancel()

    select {
    case <-hasCycle:
        fmt.Println("got a cycle")
        return true
    default:
        fmt.Println("no cycle detected")
        return false
    }
}
```

With it setup this way, you can ensure that all your calls to the go-routine will operate unless a cycle is found, in which case no additional go-routes will be called and, if you add logic to check for cancellation into `nodeHasSycle`, then you can stop execution on any running calls to it as well.

Comment: Ah interesting, what is the difference (or consequence) of putting `wg.Add(1)` in the goroutine?

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't seem to short-circuit when a cycle is found since we wait on `wg` on the main thread.
Second paragraph: "I would like to run a goroutine for each node and terminate when the first cycle is detected or when there are no cycles."

Comment: @Algebra8 If you call `wg.Add` you're updating a counter inside the wait group. `wg.Wait` blocks until that counter reaches zero. So, if you call `wg.Add` inside the go routine then there's no guarantee that the counter will be updated before `wg.Wait` gets called, which puts your wait group into an invalid state when you consider what `wg.Done` does.

Comment: @Algebra8 As for your solution, let me modify my response. I didn't quite understand what you were asking in that regard.

Comment: @Algebra8 I modified the response. See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: That's a great point about putting `wg.Add(1)` in the main thread. If I'm not mistaken, doesn't that mean we don't need the sleep?

Comment: Also, good point about putting cancellation (or short-circuiting behavior) in `nodeHasCycle`. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because I think the context in `nodeHasCycle` sounds like the way to go plus `wg.Add(1)` on the main thread is a great point and removes the need for sleep.

Comment: @Algebra8 Yes, you should be able to remove the timeout. Also, be sure to add `defer cancel()` after you call `wg.Wait` or the context will be retained in memory indefinitely (a context leak).

Comment: Unless you have some I/O, the use of context seems not very practical. Imagine you start 8 goroutines in parallel and the first one find a cycle: how do you want to stop the other goroutines? Your algorithm search for cycles AND cancelation? Seems not very practical.

Comment: One approach is to have fixed number of goroutines waiting for work (work pool). Once you find the cycle you can just stop send requests to the goroutines. Channels are a very good structure for this. And instead send a boolean you can just close the “done” channel.

Comment: However… if two goroutines find a cycle it may panic.

Comment: if it were not any context, when `len(adj)>0` and the numbers of writes `co <- true` is also > than 1, then, that implementaton will leave stuck routines on the stack. The context is convoluted, the channel `hasCycle` should simply be initialized with `make(chan bool, len(c.b))`. the sleep is useless, to say the least.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj I think managing a channel over a number of worker routines is much more annoying than using a cancel function and context, especially if you have a possibility of panicking. Using context, I don't have to worry about the function panicking.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj That being said, I'd be really interesting in seeing your solution using channels. Why don't you post an answer?